# Source of NMEA sentences in Android LocationManager

Tags: java, android, gps, android-gps, android-developer-api

I have a Note2 that stopped providing proper GPS location information due to the [WNRO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPS_Week_Number_Rollover).

I can see from logging NMEA sentences that a wrong date is delivered, and furthermore that the satfix is lost every couple of seconds/minutes. The Note2 is using a binary proprietary driver (gpsd) by Broadcom to interact with the chip. To see if this can be fixed (as I did on some other devices), I need to know what is responsible in Android to output NMEA sentences.

Are NMEA sentences always output directly by the GPS chip and the respective drivers into a named pipe, or are NMEA sentences generated by the LocationManager-framework/API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NMEA sentence are generated by the GPS chip and, for example,

through the `android.location.GpsStatus.NmeaListener`

> Used for receiving NMEA sentences from the GPS.

By implementing this interface and calling

> LocationManager#addNmeaListener to receive NMEA data from the GPS
>   engine.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/GpsStatus.NmeaListener

Both quotes indicate that the NMEA sentences are not being generated by the Android Location API.

Note: I referenced a deprecated interface (GpsStatus.NmeaListener) since Note2 is an old device and most probably is using it.

Comment: So the firmware/driver of the GPS chip is accountable for generating correct NMEA sentences?

Comment: What I can say is that you'll receive some raw NMEA packets with, for example, the `onNmeaReceived()` callback.  The NMEA sentences received are presumably to be correct.